# Как удалять либо скрывать объекты?

Tags: qml

Пытаюсь cкрыть либо удалить элемент (кнопку)

Вот код:

```
    //при нажатии на  кнопку  пытаюсь удалить кнопку button2
    Button {
        id: button2 
        text: qsTr("DRINA")

        ToolTip.visible: hovered
        ToolTip.text: qsTr("Save the active project")
    }
    Button {
        id: button3
        text: qsTr("delete")

        ToolTip.visible: hovered
        ToolTip.text: qsTr("delete the active project")
        clicked: button2. // увы но он не предлагает варианты типа delete и hide
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Также я хочу скрыть либо удалить элемент типа ColumnLayout (надеюсь это делается также как с элементом Button)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сокрытия кнопки предлагаю использовать её свойство visible, которое унаследовано от класса Item.

Для того, чтобы написать обработчки к сигналу signalName() нужно использовать слот onSignalName. В данном случае это onClicked.

```js
    Button {
        id: button3
        text: qsTr("delete")

        ToolTip.visible: hovered
        ToolTip.text: qsTr("delete the active project")
        onClicked: {
            button2.visible = false 
        }
    }
```

Для удаления объекта предлагаю ознакомиться с [Qml Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html)

Answer (score 1):

`visible` Чтобы скрыть кнопку, надо установить сигналу значение `false`. Также я допустил ошибку: `clicked` неправильный вызов сигнала. Самому сигналу ничего не следует назначать. Вместо этого я определяю onClicked обработчик сигнала. Код должен выглядеть так:

```
Button {
    id: button3
    text: qsTr("delete")

    ToolTip.visible: hovered
    ToolTip.text: qsTr("delete the active project")
    onClicked: button2.visible = false
}
```

Я не могу удалить элемент QML, который был определен статически, как я показываю. Но я могу только "скрыть" его. Также если я изменю код на динамическое создание кнопок (например, с помощью Loader), то эти кнопки можно будет удалить.

```
Component {
    id: dynamicBtn
    Button {
        // Кнопка, которую можно удалить 
    }
}

Loader {
    id: btnLoader
    sourceComponent: dynamicBtn
}

Button {
    // Выгрузить (удалить) другую кнопку 
    onClicked: btnLoader.sourceComponent = undefined
}
```

---

этот ответ является вольным переводом от [сюда :3 (спасибо jarmen-y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163947/how-do-i-delete-or-hide-objects/67164334)